# Speed of ball changes when it hits something when I only changed the direction of the ball

Tags: java, pong

I'm making pong for a project, but for some reason whenever the ball bounces off of any wall or paddle, the speed changes. I tried to make it so that only the direction is flipped. I'm not sure what went wrong can anyone please help? I made a collision class and flipped the `xVel` (`-xVel`) when it hit a paddle and flipped the `yVel` when it hit the top or bottom, but for some reason, the speed of the ball changes when it hits any paddle or the top or bottom of the screen. I put my collision and move methods below:

```js
public void collision()
{
 if(ball.intersects(p1.paddle))
 {
  xVel = - xVel;
 }
 if(ball.intersects(p2.paddle))
 {
  xVel = - xVel;
 }
}
public void move()
{
 collision();
 ball.x += xVel;
 ball.y += yVel;
 //Bounce the ball when edge detected
 if(ball.x<=0)
 {
  p2Score++;
  reset();
 }
 if(ball.x>=690)
 {
  p1Score++;
  reset();
 }
 if(ball.y<=22)
 {
  yVel = -yVel;
 }
 if(ball.y>=490)
 {
  yVel = -yVel;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe how you're measuring the ball's speed? I can't see any obvious reason why your code should change hypot(xVel, yVel).

Comment: When I run the program, whenever the ball hits something it gets substantially slower or faster. I'm new to this site and I'm not sure how to show the code entirely

Comment: One basic check is to look at the direction of travel of the ball - if this looks like a mirror reflection (as it should), then that should be a pretty good sign that the code is sensible given that you're only changing either xVel or yVel. It's possible that the speed of the ball in pixels/loop is unchanged, but for some other reason the code is slowing down so that number of pixels per second is changing?

Comment: Yes. I made it so that the ball would only bounce up and down, so there is no xVel (set xVel to 0) only yVel and after hitting the top of the screen it takes 2.81 seconds to travel to the bottom while it takes only 1.37 seconds to travel to the top of the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any side-effects in your program from reflecting the direction of travel. One thing you could try is replacing your boundary tests with something like "if (ball.y <= 22 && yVel < 0)..." etc.

Comment: Nothing changed. Is there any way to let me show you how the program would run??

Comment: I think I found the mistake of my program, since x and y are integers, and xVel and yVel are doubles, when the program tries to add xVel and yVel to  x and y it will round it to 1 or 2, therefore making the speed change (it's basically a double in speed)

Comment: Good to hear that you've found the source of the problem.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your help too. Much appreciated